# Can I keep the token persistent on protected routes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, parse-platform, react-router, parse-server

Sorry if the question is badly phrased. I am working with React.js and Parse Server at school. The issue is the following:

I would like to have protected routes, just for users that are currently logged in, and I am trying to do it by using the `.getSessionToken()` Parse built-in function. I retrieve the token successfully, get access to the protected routes only if I am logged in, but as soon as I refresh the page, the route is inaccessible again because the token is updated.

I have a working solution, but it creates some issues at the moment. The issue is that even if I have access on the page, there's the following error in the console: `No routes matched location "/page1"`

**Do you have any idea of how I can prevent the token from updating or any other more elegant solution for this issue?**

My code is the following:

1.When logging in, I pass a setter using `useState()` through props, all the way to the `App.js` where the routes are. The only reason I set the token here is in order to navigate to the next page which is protected.

```
await Parse.User.logIn(username, password);
const currentUser = Parse.User.current();
const currentToken = currentUser.getSessionToken();
setSessionToken(currentToken);
navigate("/page1");
```

2.Here, I am checking if a user is currently in my local storage, and if yes, get the token associated with the user.

```
   //sessionToken = the one I pass with props from step 1
   const [sessionToken, setSessionToken] = useState();
   //This makes sure that I get the token again and again if page is refreshed
   const [refreshedToken, setRefreshedToken] = useState();

   const authenticateUser = async () => {
    if (Parse.User.current() !== null) {
      const token = Parse.User.current().getSessionToken();
      setRefreshedToken(token);
    }
   };

   useEffect(async () => {
    await authenticateUser();
   }, []);
```

3.Since I have 2 state variables now, I make a conditional rendering by using both.

```
            <Route
                path="/login"
                element={<LoginPage setSessionToken={setSessionToken} />}
            />
{(sessionToken !== undefined || refreshedToken !== undefined) && (
          <Fragment>
            <Route path="/page1" element={<Page1 />} />
            <Route path="/page2" element={<Page2 />} />
            <Route path="/page3" element={<Page3 />} />
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue here is that you are attempting to navigate to a path `"/page1"` *before* the component rendering the routes knows it should be rendering them, hence the `No routes matched location "/page1"` error.

You may want to create an `AuthWrapper` component that checked the sessionStorage and token and renders an `Outlet` for nested routes you want to protect, otherwise redirect the users to another page, i.e. to home or login.

```
import { Outlet, Navigate, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

const AuthWrapper = (props) => {
  const location = useLocation();

  ... business logic to check sesstionStorage/token ...

  return (sessionToken !== undefined || refreshedToken !== undefined)
    ? <Outlet />
    : <Navigate to="/login" replace state={{ from: location }} />
};
```

Now declare the routes, wrapping the routes you want to protect in the `AuthWrapper` layout component.

```
<Route
  path="/login"
  element={<LoginPage setSessionToken={setSessionToken} />}
/>
<Route element={<AuthWrapper /* pass any session props here */ />}>
  <Route path="/page1" element={<Page1 />} />
  <Route path="/page2" element={<Page2 />} />
  <Route path="/page3" element={<Page3 />} />
</Route>
```

Comment: Hi Drew! I will try it and I will keep you updated. I think that your suggestion makes total sense.